# Windows phone8 xaml panorama dynamic binding

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am working on a windows phone 8 reader application.

I am using panorama control to display book pages.When I refresh panorama `itemsource` it automatically scroll's to first item.how to avoid it? Any help..?

Comment: you want the panorama to return on the page it was before refreshing rite?

Answer (score 2):

```
Panorama p = new Panorama();

int index = p.selectedIndex;
```

here p.selectedIndex returns you the index of current page. Store this index before refresh and when the page loaded set

```
p.selectedIndex = index;
```